# Why are snaps so bulky?

Tags: package-management, snap

As an example, on my system `apt-get` needs to download 3.5 MB to install the IDE geany, while the download size is 100 MB for snap. This is so big and unacceptable! Even the Windows installer of geany is no more than 15.4 MB in size!

What libraries used by a software are included in its snap file? And what are assumed to be already present on the OS? Does a snap file include all the required libraries? If that is the case, why? I see no reason why more than one copy of each specific version of a library, say GTK, should be present on a system.

Maybe I haven't understood the snap system well enough. Maybe the download size of each snap depends on the snaps already installed. For example, maybe if another application installed by snap uses the same version of GTK, the download size for snap installation of geany would be less than 100 MB.

Answer (score 7):

I think you answered your own question. Snaps are bulky because they also include some dependencies, and are thus "self-contained" apps. There are pros and cons.

The reason you would have more than one instance of a library on a system is because there could be different versions required, especially if you're running older apps. I think for newer apps that uses the latest dependencies, this should rarely be an issue.

If you have no dependency issues, there is no real reason to use snaps - this is especially true for servers. For myself, I've had little reason to install snaps over apt packages (also because the snaps I tried was not maintained, and thus had less functionality than the corresponding apt packages).

Comment: Thanks. My question indirectly asks: Is it necessary for snaps to be so bulky? It seems to me that it is possible to have some of the good properties of snaps (like updates, which are not available for most deb packages in Ubuntu) and also smaller package sizes at the same time. Each version of a library can be installed once (especially the libraries which are used often) and used by many apps.

Comment: I believe it's necessary because of the purpose of snaps - to be self-contained. Also remember that Ubuntu focuses on stability rather than cutting edge versions of apps. If you want cutting edge, consider another distribution.
However, you could either add Debian repos yourself and install apps from there or you could add Ubuntu development repos, which has more recent packages versions. However, this would lead to more manual package management to take care of versions etc.

Comment: @apadana Those "updates" which you list as the good property of snaps are exactly what lead to a duplication of dependencies.  If you want to update a package you often need updated versions of that package's dependencies.  For example, maybe you want to update some package foo on Ubuntu 18.04 from version 1 to version 2.  But version 2 requires libssl 1.1.1 and Ubuntu 18 ships with 1.1.0.  Well, there are breaking changes between the two libssl versions.  How will you make sure none of the other packages that depend on libssl (and there are many) won't be broken?

Comment: @ArturMeinild, I doubt that this degree of being self-contained is desirable. After all, dynamic linking was devised to make softwares and load times smaller. I can remember that on ubuntu 18.04 it took many seconds for calculator (a small program frequently used) to open because it was a snap! These file sizes and load times are not interesting at all. Maybe what is needed is not software packages containing all their required libraries, but smarter package managers. It is a waste of resources if each application that uses, say, a popular library like libcairo contains a copy of it.

Comment: @Pace, It appears to me that this problem is solvable by a smart package manager and a standard which developers can comply with. I personally use on a system two different versions of OpenMPI but I have to manually "tell" programs to use this one or that one. I see no unsolvable problem with two or more versions of libssl being on the same system. When a package is being installed it gives the list of its dependencies (together an acceptable range of versions for them) to the package manager. Then package managers downloads and installs them.

Comment: @Pace, the package manager may also keep for each package the number of packages that are dependent on it. If this number reaches to zero, the package manager can uninstall it automatically.

Comment: @Pace, It is not even necessary that the developers in canonical make the packages themselves. The developers of each application can build their own packages and register them in the database of the package manager. In this regard this is like Windows: if a software cannot be installed the responsibility is not usually by the OS.

Comment: @apadana Part of the problem is that there is a lot of backwards compatibility in the Linux kernel.  libraries are installed globally.  When a package depends on libssl it does not make a launch/runtime request to the OS to fetch the best available libssl package according to a range specifier.  Instead it just starts searching LD_LIBRARY_PATH until it finds a file named libssl.so and it uses that.  So this mechanism would need to change and it would likely require change in all rpms/debs to adapt.

Comment: It certainly "could" be done.  NPM's package manager is decent at trying to dedupe and then falling back to dupilcate libraries if the range specifiers are not compatible.  I'm just not sure it could be done purely in the OS without making change to child libs and then there are just too many of those to get them to agree on any consistent approach.

Comment: @Pace, You are totally right about the problem related to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. In my opinion, snap is a way to escape such problems, not a real solution. A solution can be running each application not directly, but via some kind of script which first sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I manually use this method when I have multiple versions of a library on my system. Another possible solution is that each application gets the paths of its dependencies from a package manager dynamically. This needs a standard.

Answer (score 5):

Correct, **Snaps** are much bulkier than regular packages because they are an alternative way to distribute and install apps by being self contained by including all their dependencies within themselves.

**Advantages of Snaps:**

- Always contain the correct version dependencies that the developer intended - this avoids dependency issues especially common with unmaintained apps on Linux.
- Run in a self-contained manner on the PC, in some cases this is better security
- Automatically update in the background
- Works on any Linux distro
- User-friendly for new users

**Downsides of Snaps:**

- Larger download and install size due to bundling all specific packages, instead of reusing those that may be on the system already.
- 3rd party maintenance of some Snaps is not great (This is true of all package managers really, but often the Snap may be updated later than the individual packages sometimes by a random 3rd party who may just stop at some point. Generally, popular established apps with a strong organization behind them work well with Snap if the org uses it as their main distribution method, younger/smaller apps less so).
- While the dependencies are the ones intended by the developer, there might be newer better versions coming out frequently which the app will not use.
- There may be some extra steps to allow permissions (just like Android or Windows Store apps which are similarly containerized).
- Centrally controlled by Canonical (i.e. There is only one central Snap repo, nobody can start up their own. In contrast Flatpak is an alternative without this limitation). This might be an advantage for new users who would like the simplicity of just one possible store.
- Due to running in their own container, sometimes Snap applications do not reflect the current OS theme and style. Though I believe this is partially addressed by installing "common-themes" Snaps that match containerized apps to the current OS theme.

**What I personally use Snap for**

- When its a popular app backed by a large organization and the Snap is published directly by that organization.  Examples: Blender, Inkscape, VLC.  **This is key for me personally: Developer must directly and strongly support the use of Snap as a main distribution method.**
- When I encounter bugs which are often due to unforeseen changes in new versions of dependencies. In this case I will try switching to self-contained packages like Snap or Flatpak for that app.

**All other instances I would prefer the Ubuntu apt package manager.**

Also note that in some cases, if Canonical decides the Snap package is better in all ways than the version of an app you installed via apt, *Ubuntu will automatically install the Snap instead without notifying you(!)*

Comment: Adding to your good list of disadvantages, due to the nature of how they work, Snaps require more effort on the part of the developers/packagers to build, verify, and publish than regular DEB packages (and, based on my experience, more than Docker images too, which solve a lot of the same issues but don't play nice with graphical apps to the same degree). This is a large part of why there's often lag with the updates to Snap packages.

Comment: 'Automatically update in the background' is not an advantage to some, including me. It's a huge downside.